# Solution to the boundary value problem $y''+\left(\frac{(1-e^{-4x})^2}{2x^3}-\frac{2(1-e^{-4x})}{x}\right)y'-\frac{(1-e^{-4x})^4}{16x^4} y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

> Solve the following boundary value problem
>   $$y''+\left(\frac{(1-e^{-4x})^2}{2x^3}-\frac{2(1-e^{-4x})}{x}\right)y'-\frac{(1-e^{-4x})^4}{16x^4} y=0, \quad y(0)=y(\tfrac{1}{2})=0.$$

Note: I attempted to use the generalized exponential integral $$Ein(z)\equiv \int_{0}^{z}\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm{d}t$$ to represent the solution. But it seems that I cannot do this directly.

Comment: I've removed the tag [tag:asymptotics] since this question doesn't seem to be about asymptotics.